# Как правильно преобразовать в один массив?

Tags: php

есть такой метод который принимает массив

```html
private function prepare(array $countAds): array
    {

    }
```

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно преобразовать данный массив

```html
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "moderation" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "not-published" => 59
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "published" => 2
  ]
]
```

в необходимый вид

```html
array:3 [▼
  "moderation" => 2
  "not-published" => 59
  "published" => 2  
]
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов, чтоб не делать еще один вложенный foreach, можно воспользоваться функций для работы с массивами key(). Она вернет индекс текущего элемента массива, который мы и запишем в качестве ключа нашего нового массива:

```
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $newArr[key($v)] = $v[key($v)];
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

$arr = [
  ["moderation" => 2],
  ["not-published" => 59],
  ["published" => 2],
];

$res = [];
foreach($arr as $i => $value) {
  foreach($value as $key => $n) {
    $res[$key] = $n;
  }
}

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]